# finding documents in a collection that match an array of ids

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So, I have a collection in MongoDB named **cart**. All documents in cart have a field **cartItems**, a dynamic array, which contains **productID s**. I want to query cartItems and use it to find the matching productIDs in another collection called **Products** that contains details of all the products I have.

Here's the **cartItems** field in a document of collection **cart**.

```
 "cartItems" : [ 
    {
        "productID" : "64ac60de872e",
        "quantity" : 5
    }, 
    {
        "productID" : "13528471cb73",
        "quantity" : 5
    }, 
    {
        "productID" : "e64ac60de8732",
        "quantity" : 5
    }
]
```

and here's a document in **Products** that has some details of product with **productID = "64ac60de872e"**

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("64ac60de872e"),
   "Name" : "something",
   "Category" : "cat1",
}
```

Here's what I've tried doing so far using a helper function in Meteor.

```
  Template.cart.helpers({
   carts: function () {  
   var user = cart.find().fetch()[0];
   var id=[];
   for(i=0;i<user.cartItems.length; i++) {
    id.push(new Mongo.ObjectID(user.cartItems[i].productID));
    console.log(id[i]);
   }
   return Products.find({"_id": { $all :id}});
  }
```

I'm calling this helper in an html file that prints the **Name** and **Category** but this isn't working.

If I do

```
 return Products.find({"_id": id[i]})
```

where i=0,1,2  it works and prints the details of that particular element

I'd really appreciate if someone tells me where I'm going wrong. I feel like I'm making this really complicated and there is a simpler solution.

Comment: what's the problem with $all though? why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mongo [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) is equivalent to `$and`, so to match you would need a record with an `_id` array containing every value.

What you want is [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in), where it just needs to match one of the values in the array.

Here's how I would do it. I've also tidied a couple of other things and added comments for why:

```
  Template.cart.helpers({
   carts: function () {  
   // `findOne` will also return the first result
   var user = cart.findOne();
   // Map creates a new array from the result of running the supplied
   // function over every record
   var id = user.cartItems.map(item => new Mongo.ObjectId(item.productId));
   return Products.find({ "_id": { $in: id } });
  }
```

Comment: alright so I implemented what you wrote and printed the id variable in the console. I saw that it was giving a bunch of random ids, which I think was being generated by the map function. So I put the for loop I had used before and now it is working. The problem was, like you said, with the $all. $in is the way to go. Thanks!